# How To Send Email Replies Using Gmail API

Tags: c#, gmail, gmail-api

So, I am implementing Sending Email Replies Using Various Email Providers like Gmail API, SMTP and others.

I have figured out that if we set custom Message-Id header in the emails we can send replies to those emails by adding that Message-Id value in In-Reply-To Header of the mail that is being sent as reply.

This is working in SMTP. But when I am sending mail using GmailAPI, Gmail API is overriding the custom Message-Id header that I've sent and using its own.

My question is, does Gmail API ignores our Message-Id and always generate its own? And is there any other way to implement the functionality of replying to messages.